# What is the TTL for events in Azure Event Grid with Pull model?

Tags: azure, pull, azure-eventgrid, ttl

I want to consume events from Event Grid, using [pull model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/pull-delivery-overview). I wonder how much time do I have to consume a message? For example, if my application work only on week days, can I consume an event after 72 hours (event produces on Friday, and application starts working on Monday).

I can see that TTL for push model is at most [24 hours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/manage-event-delivery), but it is not clear for me, what about pull model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***According to this [Quotas and limits - Azure Event Grid - Azure Event Grid | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/quotas-limits#events-limits-in-namespace) and This table - [Choose the right Event Grid tier for your solution - Azure Event Grid | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/choose-right-tier#basic-and-standard-tiers)***

Given the Basic tier's throughput of up to **`5 MB/s`** for both ingress and egress, and a maximum **`message retention of 1 day`**, your application must pull messages within this retention period to avoid missing any.

Firstly, converting the throughput to seconds indicates that you can pull 5 MB of data every second. Calculating the potential accumulation of data in 1 day:

**5 MB/s * 3600 seconds/hour * 24 hours/day = 432,000 MB**

Considering that there are 1024 MB in a GB:

**432,000 MB / 1024 = 421.875 GB**

This implies that you can accumulate approximately **`421.875`** GB of messages within 1 day.

To determine the time available to consume a message, divide the total accumulated data by the throughput rate:

**421.875 GB * 1024 MB/GB / 5 MB/s = 86,015.625 seconds**

This translates to roughly **`23.89 hours`**.

***Therefore, you have approximately **`23.89 hours`** to consume a message from Event Grid using the pull model before it expires, based on the Basic tier's throughput and message retention of  1 Day. The duration available for consuming messages from Azure Event Grid using the pull model is determined by the maximum event retention period allocated for namespace topics, which is set to 7 days as per the provided limits.***